# Redirect website from within frame PHP

Tags: php, javascript, frame, redirect

I have a web page, let's call it main.php which displays an image of football field and some players distributed on the field. However, that page uses list.php as a right side frame that loads a list of players.

**What happens is**, when the user clicks on a player on the field (main.php), let's say on the image of the Goal Keeper (GK), a list of GKs from world wide teams will load in right list fram (list.php). This is by using ajax.

So far we are good.

**The current situation is**, when session times out and the user clicks on a player from the field, the list on the right does not load, instead, list of players disappears from the list and a message says "Please login" is displayed on the right side frame (list.php)

**The objective is**, when session times out I want the whole website to redirect to the main page index.php

**The problem is**, I already put the redirecting code just before the code that is responsible of displaying the message "Please login". But what happened is, the redirection happens from within the frame, so i ended up having main.php displaying the field, and list.php displaying the main page!

Here's the code I added.

```
$user_id = NSession::get('user_id');
 if (!isset($user_id))
{
        NSession::removeall();         
        General::Redirect('index.php');
}
```

They are using Smarty. and btw, I added the same code to top of main.php, and now if user tries to access main.php without logging in, it will redirect him to the main page, so the code works!

n.b. The project is not mine, it belongs to the company I work in.
And I don't know which code is checking the session, all what I know is, if the user click on a player from the field after the session timeout, the "Please Login" message will be shown in the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the redirect is essentially the same as using a header() function.  It isn't possible to specify a target using a php redirect as it is server-side - specifying the target is client-side.

You would need to print something like this to the screen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('index.php','_parent');</script>
```

And that will redirect the user to the index.

Answer (score 0):

Using frames for such purpose is... well... so 80ish...

Anyway, the frames are probably named in such a scenario. This means you can address them, but also that you have to address them. Just loading an url inside the "current" frame does exactly that, which is why your approach won't work.

If you really have to go with that frame based approach, then you will have to use javascript to address all known frames and redirect them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some javascript inside of your frame like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.top.location = 'YourPage.html';

</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Used that already. Same result. It loads from within the frame.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the session expires while I'm on main.php. Therefore, any subsequent Ajax requested will fail since all requests requires session to be active.

the problem was that the Ajax request being sent from the IFrame (the IFrame is inside main.php and points to list.php thru Ajax calls) is failing due to session expiry.

So I've fixed this issue by adding another two session checks, one on main.php, list.php using PHP (check for session, if it's there, redirect). And in the main container, main.php, I check for the session via JS, interval Ajax requests to check the session, if session has ended, then use redirect using JS.

PHP:

```
 $user_id = NSession::get('user_id');
if (isset($_POST["checklogin"]))//check loging
{
    die(isset($user_id) ? "true" : "false");
}
if (!isset($user_id) || $user_id == "")
{
   NSession::removeall();
   General::Redirect('login.php');
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(window).focus(function() {
        checkSession();
    });
});


function checkSession()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {"checklogin": "cl"},
        url: "list_players.php",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result === "false")
            {
                if (FIELD.showMessage === false)
                {
                    FIELD.showMessage = true;
                    alert("Your session has been closed\nYou will be redirected to login page now. ");
                    window.location.href = ("login.php");//incase user clicks OK                   
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```